# I cannot enter the device configuration

Tags: 18.04, gnome, configuration, brightness, tools

I use ubuntu 18.04 and I was moving some gnome-network manager with the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

And now I can't find the configuration application where it is located: displays, bluetoth, wifi, mouse, brightness, battery, about, etc ... can I reinstall it?

Comment: Are you looking for `gnome-control-center` ? Why removing `network-manager-gnome` and  `network-manager` ?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome network manager is part of Gnome settings. Simply reinstall them with:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

and you should be back to the previous situation. A reboot might be necessary.

In the future, when you're installing or uninstalling anything, notice what will be removed before confirming. Uninstalling some packages might remove much more than you intend to remove.